# Rails test with triggers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I noticed that Rails creates triggers in the development db but not the test db since it creates the test db from schema.rb instead of running migrations. I have a trigger (as a migration) and need to test that it does the right thing, how can I do that? I tried adding the trigger manually to the test db but that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default rails sets up the test database using the database independant schema.rb, which doesn't understand stuff like triggers.

If you change `config.active_record_schema_format` to `:sql` then rails will instead dump the raw SQL that represents the development database's structure and use that to recreate the test database. This dump is placed in development.sql, which is then used instead of schema.rb

This dump is done using the command line tools that your db provides and so will respect features like triggers that active record isn't aware of

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried doing that but it didn't work. The problem is that the trigger is not showing in schema.rb after I ran the migration even though it's showing on the development db. Maybe because I added the trigger as a sql code? But I couldn't find any other way to add the trigger

Comment: Ok I got it to work finally! I uncommented the line in test.rb config.active_record.schema_format = :sql and then ran RAILS_ENV=test db:migrate and the trigger was added. Thanks again!

Comment: When you do this schema.rb is no longer use at all - there should be a development.sql that is used instead. You would need to do rake db:test:prepare (unless you're running rake test, rake spec etc which do that for you)

Comment: I'm getting `structure.sql` (with Rails 5?) instead of `development.sql`. And although I get trigger alright creating test DB, it gets disabled when I run `rails test`. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you do prefer Ruby dumps to SQL dumps you might give this gem a try:

https://github.com/jovoto-team/trackless_triggers

It supports dumping triggers and functions for mysql.